# how to connect docker container to a remote database?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, docker, docker-container

I started docker tutorial a couple of days ago. I am trying to connect to a remote database. I don't know how to add the database URL in my `yml` file
This is the database that I want to connect to: `mydomainuat1.mydomain.com:1531/myuat`.
Below is my `yml` file.

```
version: "3"

services:

  mydb:
    image: 7bb2586065cd
     ports:
      - "3306:1531"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD:1
      - MYSQL_DATABASE:students
      - MYSQL_USER:kaka
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD:kaka1234
  networks:
      - my-network

  ws:
    image: 92c203b7b219
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    depends_on:
      - mydb
    networks:
      - my-network



  networks:
    my-network:
    driver: overlay
```

Comment: If you using remote DB, then no need to create service for that in yml file and no need of image.  In your code, you can directly configure the DB details and use. Just make sure that your application can reach to remote DB

Comment: If this is a remote database, not the database you have defined in your yml file, you would have to pass this `url` to container with your spring-boot app using `environment variables` and replace the url in your `application.properties` - you will have to modify the `ENTRYPOINT` of image with your app to take environment variable that is passed during creation of the container and override the property of your database url in `java -jar ...` command.

Comment: Sameer K I dont want to write the database credentials in my code. Before docker, I used jndi datasouce to supply the credentials.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? If not, please update your question. Otherwise, please close it.

Comment: Any update on this? i am facing the same issue. My database is at some remote url and i am not able to connect my dockerized application with that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you mixed up something here. What you do in your `docker-compose.yml` is defining a `mydb` service, which will start a DB on your Docker host. Your `ws` service then can connect to this DB using `mydb:1531`. 
(The port mapping to `3306` is also not necessary if you want only the `ws` container to communicate with the DB, as they don't rely on host ports.)

If you want to reach a remote DB on another machine, you don't need the `mydb` service at all, just pass the connection details into your `ws` container like you already did for the `mydb` service and go on from there.